# Would I be considered a "job-hopper"/unprofessional?

Tags: job-search, career-development, quitting, careers

I'm a 3rd/4th year CS student. A year ago, i did a 3-month internship at a software company, and two months ago I got hired at another company as a Junior Developer for a trial period of three months. Back then, I had told them that I would be able to continue to work here part-time after the trial period. And I'm pretty sure they will want me to continue working for them. I recently realized two things:

- I don't think I'll manage to both work at this company and finish my degree
- I don't really enjoy this job (I want to try other things)

I'm probably going to quit and get a job that fits me better in two years, after I finish my degree. So, to finally ask my question(s):

- Will the two 3-month jobs seem as "job-hopping" to a potential employer?
- Am I unprofessional for changing my mind about working after the summer break?
- Can I use the facts that I'm still a student and that it's a trial period in my defense?

Comment: Did the first 3 month intership was from your own initiative or a necessity for your degree ? 2 times seems low to be considered to be a job hopper, and you're not even force to put those two experience in your resume if you don't think one doesn't bring anything positive in your resume (which is unlikely tbh). Note that trial period are for both party, they're testing you and you're testing them.

Comment: @Walfrat It was partly a necessity (I was only required to do 1 month). I suppose you're right about the trial period going both ways. I think it's just that I feel bad about creating problems for people I like (my team).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I'm probably going to quit and get a job that fits me better in two
>   years, after I finish my degree. So, to finally ask my question(s):
>
> Will the two 3-month jobs seem as "job-hopping" to a potential
>   employer?

You are a student. While still in school, it's not unusual to have a series of short-term internships/jobs. Employers don't consider that "job hopping".

> Am I unprofessional for changing my mind about working after the
>   summer break?

No. Your studies are more important than short-term jobs. You just realized that you aren't capable of doing both at the same time. Notify them as soon as possible. They may be disappointed, but will likely understand.

> Can I use the facts that I'm still a student and that it's a trial
>   period in my defense?

I don't see that you need a "defense".

Comment: Nothing to see here...everything the OP is doing is perfectly normal and explainable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It may seem silly from the outside, but it's really been making me feel guilty and nervous for the past few days.